# How to read "what we"?

Tags: pronunciation

For example, there is a sentence:

```
This is just what we are looking for
```

When we read it fast, how to read "what we"?

1. "what we", the `t` is soft
2. "wha twe", the `tw` is read together like in `tween`

Which is correct?

PS: I have the same problem with `that we` and other word before `we` with `t` ending. Are they having the same rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the accent.  In my normal voice (south east British middle class) it's the first one.  When I talk in Received Pronunciation, it's the second.  In some accents, the t sound might disappear completely.

The first sounds more natural to me, but that may be because it's my own accent.